# My multilayer NN converges too slowly(practically not usable)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

My dataset is like this:
i have 7 letters(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) written in 9(lines)x7(columns) each, using '#' and '-', where '#' is 1 and '-' is -1.
Of each letter there are 3 fonts, so i have a total of 21 characters.
N of input neurons: 63
hidden:1
output:7
A target for letter 'b' is: -1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1(because the second letter in alphabet is 'b').
Learning rate: 1
Method: backpropagation with delta rule.
activation function: bipolar sigmoid.
Random weights between -0.5 and 0.5.
After the 600000th epoch, the MSE is about 58, and decreases by 0,006, then by 0,003 and so on.
I tried increasing the learning rate and the number of hidden neurons, but it starts to diverge if i do that.
I don't think my neural network is wrong since it can resolve xor in 300 epoch, and can learn 2 letters immediately(if i use only 2 letter in input).
I really need to get it working since i want it to be my final school project.
How much time should a NN take to resolve such a problem?
Where am I wrong?
Could you suggest me a software or a site where i can build a NN and check if the implementation is correct?
Thanks.

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer - "where am I wrong" with no code, and a project that works but is slow... I like the "Deep Learning Toolbox" as a reference implementation in Matlab, but you haven't even given us a language, so there's no way to advise. There is a massive amount of literature on increasing convergence time, but at the end of the day it will all depend on your individual data

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the error, I confused the counter of an inner for with the outer's one. Now it takes less than 1 second(<30 epoch) to learn 21 characters, with a configuration of 63-4-7. Sorry for the trouble.